# Webpack and Webpack-cli compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-cli

I upgraded webpack from 5.70.0 to 5.75.0 my webpack-cli is at 4.9.2

When I try to npm install my project it crashes saying:
npm ERR! notarget no matching version found for webpack-cli@5.0.1

The company I work for uses their own artifactory where the latest webpack-cli is at 4.9.2

Why is the project trying to install 5.0.1 if my package.json I have specified 4.9.2

Comment: Please include some more information. Could it be a peer-dependency issue?